# Static variable and object life span in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ and I understand  basic concepts of "pass-by-value or reference", object scope and object instantiation with and without use of the keyword "new" in simple examples. The problem is that when the problems that I'm trying to solve become more complicated, I don't know how is this theory I know from simple examples applied in problems that consists of multiple classes.

I have a PaintWidget.cpp which is responsible for painting all the Vehicles.

```
void PaintWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
   if (!Vehicle::GetVehicles()->empty()) {
    cout << "not null" << endl;

    QPainter painter(this);

    QPen pen1(Qt::red);
    pen1.setWidth(2);

    std::vector<Vehicle>::iterator it;
    for (it = Vehicle::GetVehicles()->begin(); it != Vehicle::GetVehicles()->end(); it++) {
        cout << "draaaaw" << endl;
        QRect rect(it->GetXcord(), it->GetYcord(), it->GetWidth(), it->GetHeight());
        cout << std::to_string(it->GetXcord()) + " " + std::to_string(it->GetYcord()) + " " + std::to_string(it->GetWidth()) + " " + std::to_string(it->GetHeight()) + " " << endl;
        painter.setPen(pen1);
        painter.drawRect(rect);
    }
} else {
    cout << "is null" << endl;
}
}
```

And then I have Vehicle.h

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle();
    Vehicle(const Vehicle& orig);
    virtual ~Vehicle();

    void initVehicles();

    Vehicle createVehicle();

    static std::map<Road, int> &GetVeh_num() {
        return veh_num;
    }

    static std::vector<Vehicle> *GetVehicles() {
        return &vehicles;
    }


private:
    int xcord;
    int ycord;
    int height = 20;
    int width = 50;
    static std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles;
    static std::map<Road, int> veh_num;
};

#endif  /* VEHICLE_H */
```

Vehicle.cpp

```
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<Vehicle> Vehicle::vehicles;
std::map<Vehicle::Road, int> Vehicle::veh_num = {
    {Vehicle::Top, 0},
    {Vehicle::Right, 0},
    {Vehicle::Bottom, 0},
    {Vehicle::Left, 0}
};

Vehicle::Vehicle() {
}

Vehicle::Vehicle(const Vehicle& orig) {
}

Vehicle::~Vehicle() {
}


int Vehicle::GetXcord() const {
    return xcord;
}

int Vehicle::GetYcord() const {
    return ycord;
}

void Vehicle::SetXcord(int xcord) {
    this->xcord = xcord;
}

void Vehicle::SetYcord(int ycord) {
    this->ycord = ycord;
}

int Vehicle::GetHeight() const {
    return height;
}

int Vehicle::GetWidth() const {
    return width;
}

void Vehicle::initVehicles() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Vehicle::vehicles.push_back(this->createVehicle());
    }
}

Vehicle Vehicle::createVehicle() {
    std::map<Vehicle::Road, int>::iterator it;
    Vehicle v;
    for (it = Vehicle::veh_num.begin(); it != Vehicle::veh_num.end(); it++) {
        int &vehnum = it->second;
        if (it->first == Vehicle::Road::Right) {
            int xc = 520 + vehnum * this->GetWidth() + vehnum * 5;
            int yc = 220;
            v.SetXcord(xc);
            v.SetYcord(yc);
            v.SetRoad(Vehicle::Right);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

As you can see, createVehicle returns copy of a new Vehicle which is then inserted in the static variable Vehicles. GetVehicles returns pointer to vector of inserted vehicles because I don't want to return a copy. When I run this code, nothing gets painted although there are 5 objects in the static variable (paintEvent gets called and string "draaaaw" is printed 5 times). I suspected that I have a problem with object life span, so I changed

```
static std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles;
```

to

```
static std::vector<Vehicle*> vehicles;
```

and of course instantiation of Vehicle from

```
Vehicle v;
```

to

```
Vehicle *v = new Vehicle();
```

which creates an object on the heap if I understand correctly. After all required changes in methods, my code works (all objects are painted). What I don't understand is when these objects get destroyed and why, if I'm returning a copy every single time. How come vector vehicles is not empty (I still have 5 "ghost" objects that do not contain any values I set earlier). As far as I understand creating objects with new is not recommended, so the second option are smart pointers?

Thanks :)

Edit
I purposely left out setters and getters in .h and .cpp file so that the code is as short as possible with only relevant information.

Comment: If you are calling 'new', you'll need to have a matching 'delete' somewhere or they will never be free'd up (ie: they will still be sitting on the heap when the app terminates. the OS will reclaim the memory though).

Comment: Perhaps you've forgotten to call `initVehicles`. Generally, you should instead use constructors to initialize objects: then the compiler guarantees the call for you, and it also guarantees that you don't get multiple calls.

Comment: The PaintWidget.cpp I posted wasn't complete but the initVehicles is called in its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is you have defined an empty copy constructor:

```
Vehicle::Vehicle(const Vehicle& orig)
{
}
```

This means that when you add a `Vehicle` to a container, a copy is made that doesn't actually copy anything. You should delete your own constructor and let the compiler do the work for you.

Comment: You are right. When I deleted this constructor it worked as expected. This constructor was auto generated by netbeans and I completely missed it trying to figure auto where my objects got destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You will never have a problem with object life span if you don't use pointers or references. It simply isn't possible for that to occur. The whole concept of "RAII" is that if the variable is accessible in code, it is valid.

To test this, also print out the coordinates and size of your vehicle. If that prints a valid result, you know that your issue lies in the paint function itself.

So just don't pass a pointer of the object unless you need to modify it, and even then return a reference instead of a pointer. Just make sure not to return a reference of a temporary, as that CAN lead to life span issues.

Comment: As you can see I did in fact print out the coordinates, width and height in paintEvent. I got this: 32934224 0 50 20, 31850080 0 50 20, which is completely different from what I expected.